# Detecting openings/holes in a closed triangular mesh?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, mesh

I want to detect (and close) openings and holes/hollowed out parts of a closed mesh. I know that for an open mesh, this can be done by finding the boundary edges (edges belonging to only one triangle) as described [here](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/685741-how-to-detect-hollow-openingsholes-on-a-static-mesh/).

But what about a closed mesh, where such boundary edges don't exist? Below is an example image. The box has an opening at the top, while the cylinder has a complete hole. Is there an **algorithm** to detect these things?

[image]

Comment: And what kind of output should the algorithm give for the examples you showed?

Comment: A topologist would say the box is the same as a flat sheet, but the cylinder is different.

Comment: Those are pretty difficult tasks. For the handles (cylinder example), you might find interesting approaches [here](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~dey.8/paper/hantun-persist/hantun.pdf) and [here](http://hhoppe.com/proj/isotoposimp/). For the openings, you need to be more specific about what an opening is. Does every concave polyhedron have openings, i.e., do you just want to find the convex hull?

Comment: @DominikMokriš A list of vertices that make up the opening/hole. So for the cube it would be the inner 4 vertices on the top, and for the cylinder it would be the inner edge loop vertices from both sides

Comment: @NicoSchertler For the case of the cube in the image, a convex hull would be sufficient, but assuming a volume with one big opening and many small ones, I would ideally be able to determine all the openings, and just fill the small ones depending on the opening surface area. I'm not sure how feasible that is though.

Comment: This brings us back to the question of what an opening is. I am imagining a very irregular model - then how do you decide what to fill and what to leave? Maybe something like convex ridge loops enclosing concave edges?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I'm not sure what you mean by irregular model, but the models in question are CAD models. What decides which openings to fill is its size.

Comment: I mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjujY.png).

Comment: @NicoSchertler No nothing like that. The models are CAD models of machines (manufacturing machinery, factory lines, cars, etc...)

Comment: @NicoSchertler: the number of holes is a well defined topological concept, also called the genus of the surface. The sinuosity of the shape doesn't matter. For example, a doughnut and a mug with handle both have a single hole.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know. I am not asking about the holes. I am asking about the openings in the (closed genus-0) box or general surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of problem is studied in a field called computational topology. To distinguish the torus (or multi-torus) from the sphere, it suffices to determine whether (in the language of [homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics))) there exists a 1-cycle that is not a boundary. Assuming you have an orientable manifold, this can be done by comparing the rank/nullity of the matrices corresponding to the relevant boundary operators.

To repair the hole, my intuition would be that finding the shortest cycle that's not a boundary, filling it in, and repeating would give reasonable results, but I don't know off the top of my head how to do that algorithmically.

Comment: I won't lie, I didn't understand anything you said. But I guess you've given me quite a few terms I can search and read up on.